# Some links displayed as text in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have added links to a list of sentences in my TYPO3 backend.

In the frontend, some of these sentences are rendered properly, with a link to them. However, some others are rendered as plain text, with the  tag visible.

- [View of the text in the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2IKk.png)
- [View of the rendered text in the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM5te.png)

What caused the problem, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

your description of the error is not good enough to give a good answer. please explain more in detail what you are doing: templates, configuration, ...

for the moment I guess: you use fluid-templates and have fluid-variables which contain the rendered content.

instead of outputting the content of a field directly (like `{fieldname}`), where the rendering is done by fluid you need to output the already rendered output without interfering of fluid (`rtefieldname->f:format.raw()}`) as for RTE-fields the content is already rendered in html. otherwise all specialchars are converted to show as given.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the `<a>` tags aren't closed properly.

Try checking the HTML code from the backend (by clicking the `<>` button in the backend). See if the `</a>` tag is where it should be, at the end of each sentences.

You need to find the difference between the lines that work and the lines that don't.